# Execute DB_ID sql function from scala

Tags: sql-server, scala, jdbc

I would like to call the DB_ID function of SQL Server to retrieve the databaseID of a user database from scala..

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
        val connection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionString)
    //SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE Name
    val statement: CallableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{? =call  DB_ID(?)}")
    statement.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.INTEGER)
    statement.setString(2,s"'ABC_STORE'")
    statement.execute()
    val a = statement.getInt(1)
```

I get an error `COULD NOT FIND the stored procedure DB_ID`.

How do i get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `statement.setString` you don't need to use your `String` between the two `''` so change :

```
statement.setString(2,s"'ABC_STORE'")
```

by

```
statement.setString(2, "ABC_STORE")
```

What the `s` do in `2,s"'` make sure to remove it.

You can learn more here :

[Using a Stored Procedure with a Return Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-a-return-status) and [Prepared Statement doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)